# Connect GraphQL to PowerBI

Tags: graphql, powerbi, powerquery

I want to create my GraphQL page and connect it via M to PowerBI to visualize.
This is my code:

But my error, after signing in the error is this: Expression.Error: Access to the resource is forbidden. My graphQL query seems to work well.

In my Postman collection I also have the variables in my bode called scope and grant_type, but I'm pretty new to this.

```
let
    url = "link",
    client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

    Source = Web.Contents(
    url,
    [
        Headers=[
            #"Method"="POST",
            #"Content-Type"="application/json",
            #"client_id"=client_id,
            #"client_secret"=client_secret
        ],
        Content=Text.ToBinary("{""query"": ""{ manufacturingOrders {id product {id description} comment priority }}""}")
    ]
    ),

    #"JSON" = Json.Document(Source)
in
    JSON
```